# remove duplicate options from HTML select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a weird one but our developer is away and my client is having a web site presentation tomorrow.
On a web page one drop-down has the values below. Is there a way using script/css our designer can hide the replicated values and just show 1-9 once? Thanks so much.

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help disabling the duplicate options in select element.http://stackoverflow.com/a/9369331/1940720

Comment: Try this `http://jsfiddle.net/Eg2Np/`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var usedNames = {};
$("select > option").each(function () {
  if(usedNames[this.text]) {
     $(this).remove();
 } else {
     usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
 }});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EB3nQ/)**

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the dups using jQuery like below:

```
var found = [];
$("select option").each(function() {
  if($.inArray(this.value, found) != -1) $(this).remove();
  found.push(this.value);
});
```

Keep an array of found values, if value not found in array, add it `.push()`, if found, its a dupe, `.remove()` it.

Comment: @down_voter, please care to comment. it is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)** selector:

```
$('select option:gt(8)').hide();
```

Comment: How can I apply this to just this particular dropdown on the page

Comment: You can give your `select` an `id` then use `#` to target the element by id like: `$('#selectId option:gt(8)').hide();`

Comment: I think it is working for now but it is in reverse order it will not work because it `8` is index not a actual value.

Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set

Answer (score -1):

try this ....

```
$('select option').each(function(i)){
    if(i >= 9)
    $(this).remove();
});
```